# Kubernetes Operator-sdk 1.2 no option to run locally

Tags: kubernetes, operator-sdk

I need to test the code I developed for the operator 0.17 to 1.2 operator-sdk kit. I am struggling to understand how can I run the operator locally before build the docker image and test the same?

Is there a way to test locally without building docker images?

Answer (score 0):

operator-sdk 1.0+ scaffolds a make target `make run` for running locally.

https://github.com/operator-framework/operator-sdk/blob/master/testdata/go/v3/memcached-operator/Makefile#L40

Comment: Thanks but I didn't understand. Do I need to run just `run ./main.go`? As of now I am doing the following: ```operator-sdk init --domain=example.com
make generate
make manifests
make install
make docker-build IMG=quay.io/$USERNAME/testop:0.0.1
make deploy IMG=quay.io/$USERNAME/testop:0.0.1``` and previously I used to do the following: `operator-sdk run --local -verbose`

Comment: `make deploy` and `make docker-build` are part of the "running on the cluster" steps: https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/#2-run-as-a-deployment-inside-the-cluster

`make run` runs the operator locally, (you are right, it is executing main.go under the hood)  https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/tutorial/#1-run-locally-outside-the-cluster